# Hybrid Lock Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I have an algorithm that is painfully slow if I use 'pure' mutexes. That's because most of the critical sections are short and far shorter than the work to sleep a thread. However, it is also slower to allow the occasional long critical section cause long spins in other thread(s). This class is intended to provide a balance. The balance here is compile-time fixed. What would be interesting is an adaptive strategy for tuning the spin time.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
///<summary>A hybrid lock making a number of spin attempts
///and then entering a wait before retrying.</summary>
///<remarks>Implemented to be interface swappable 
///with <code>std::mutex</code>.</remarks>
template<unsigned SPIN_LIMIT>
class hybrid_lock {
public:
    typedef unsigned spin_count_type;
    typedef void *native_handle_type;

    inline void lock() {
        spin_count_type limit(0);
        for (;;) {
            if (!this->mFlag.test_and_set(std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire)) {
                return;
            }
            if (limit >= SPIN_LIMIT) {
                break;
            }
            ++limit;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(this->mMutex);
        this->mCondition.wait(guard, [this]() { 
            return !this>mFlag.test_and_set(
               std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire
            ); 
        });
    }

    inline bool try_lock() {
        return !this->mFlag.test_and_set(
            std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire
        );
    }

    inline void unlock() {
        this->mFlag.clear(std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
        this->mCondition.notify_one();
    }

    ///<summary>Returns the address of the flag backing the lock.</summary>
    ///<remarks>The return value may not be compatible with
    ///<code>std::mutex</code>.</remarks>
    ///<returns>The address of the flag 
    ///backing the spin-lock.</returns>
    inline native_handle_type native_handle() {
        return static_cast<native_handle_type>(&this->mFlag);
    }

    inline hybrid_lock(void) {
        mFlag.clear();
    }
private:
    std::atomic_flag mFlag;//The actual lock object.
    std::mutex mMutex;//Used to synchronize sleeping threads.
    std::condition_variable mCondition;

    hybrid_lock(const hybrid_lock&) = delete;
    hybrid_lock& operator=(const hybrid_lock&) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would expect the standard library's `mutex` (which is basically `pthread_mutex`) to already take care of this optimization behind the scenes, the same way these days I would expect the standard library's `malloc` to [maintain its own thread-local arenas](http://jamesgolick.com/2013/5/19/how-tcmalloc-works.html) instead of taking a lock on every call.

Have you benchmarked the difference between what you wrote above and

```
template<unsigned SPIN_LIMIT>
class kiss_mutex {
    std::mutex mtx_;

  public:
    void lock() {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < SPIN_LIMIT; ++i) {
            if (mtx_.try_lock()) return;
        }
        mtx_.lock();
    }

    bool try_lock() { return mtx_.try_lock(); }
    void unlock() { return mtx_.unlock(); }
};
```

? I haven't, but I'd be very curious to know whether `kiss_mutex<N>` performed comparably to `std::mutex` or comparably to `hybrid_lock<N>` (for tuneable values of `N`, of course).

---

Your benchmark might have been thrown off by a ***hilarious*** bug in `hybrid_lock::lock()`:

```
    this->mCondition.wait(guard, [this]() { 
        return !this>mFlag.test_and_set(
           std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire
        ); 
    });
```

*When you see it...*

This is the funniest argument I've seen yet for suffixing data members with `_` and never writing out `this->` except where the grammar requires it. :)

---

Stylistically, your code seems pretty good. My nits:

- I would be extremely wary of declaring template non-type parameters of type `unsigned int`. My advice is to stick with `int`, because its name is short and because it's easy to write literals of that type. The only reason I stuck with `unsigned` in `kiss_mutex` is because if I didn't, it wouldn't have been a drop-in replacement for your code.

[Here's the code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GyymNuclfPNuWCmH) showing why `unsigned` is worse than `int`: if someone sees `hybrid_lock<100>` they're probably going to assume that `100` represents an int (or at worst a `size_t`), and they're going to code accordingly, and their code *simply will not work* if you've used some other weird type. In other words, `int` is widely recognized as a ***vocabulary type*** (a ["ubiquitous type used throughout the internal interfaces of a program"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1850.pdf)), whereas `unsigned` is not generally recognized as such. Of course, `unsigned` *might* be used as a vocabulary type in your codebase; it all depends on your employer's coding style guide. But I would hope it's not, for sanity's sake (again refer back to the code in the Wandbox above).

For another set of reasons that I mostly agree with, see [Laurion Burchall's "unsigned considered harmful"](http://web.archive.org/web/20111126152936/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurionb/archive/2009/03/27/unsigned-considered-harmful.aspx). Since you mentioned you've used Java, you might like [this similarly titled blog post elsewhere, re Java,](http://www.nayuki.io/page/unsigned-int-considered-harmful-for-java) which makes some good points re "things C and C++ screwed up in their implementation of unsigned types."

- The thing you wrote is actually a *mutex* in C++ terms, not a *lock*; so it should be called `hybrid_mutex`. A *mutex* exposes imperative `lock` and `unlock` methods; a *lock* (for example, [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)) is a wrapper that hides `lock` and `unlock` under a protective layer of RAII. (In other words: If you're designing a drop-in replacement for `std::mutex`, it should almost certainly be named `something_something_mutex`.)
- In C++11, it is inappropriate to make any special member function `private`. If you want a special member function to go away, declare it `=delete` (which you did) but leave it public; this way, you're sure to get the error messages you want, instead of weird interference from the part of the compiler that checks access controls. "This constructor was explicitly deleted" is a much better error message than "This constructor is private and by the way it's been deleted too."
- [The Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/): `std::mutex` is a non-copyable type, so merely *having* a member of type `std::mutex` suffices to implicitly delete your copy operations. It's redundant to declare them deleted; you can just rip out those lines, as I did in `kiss_mutex`.
- On the same note, I've never seen anyone use the `inline` keyword as you did, on member functions that are declared in-line and are thus implicitly `inline` anyway. Keep the code clean by removing redundant keywords. (<s>Personally I make an exception for `virtual`, but my impression is that the C++ mainstream these days doesn't even make *that* exception.</s> Indeed, as of 2021, I've completely converted to the Church of `override`, and [no longer ever write `virtual` redundantly](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/58f91d7cf10f041ee2cea02425eaf88869644217/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override).)

Comment: Useful points. What is certainly clear is that in MSVC `std::mutex` doesn't take care of this. Personally I would think it not a good idea. Whether some spinning retries are worthwhile is strictly problem dependent and favours particular circumstance. Whereas a pure mutex allows this kind of hybrid. I will have a go at a `try_lock()` version.

Comment: I take the point but I must say I dislike the confused terminology of C++. If you're going to say mutex isn't a lock don't give it methods `lock()` and `unlock()`. Could be `acquire()` and `release()`. By that argument the other thing is a `spin_mutex` but the whole world calls it a spin-lock.

Comment: Making special members private is habit from the old days (pre `= delete`). I take your point about improving error messages. I will say I prefer to delete them because a compile failure on the non-copyability of a `std::mutex` isn't always a deliberate outcome - may be someone forgot to code a copy member. I prefer `= delete` to say 'not for copying by design'.

Comment: I do think things that are counts and cannot be negative should be `unsigned`. Having spent some years also coding in Java I really appreciate the added clarity of `unsigned` types.

Comment: Explicit `inline` is also a throw-back to the olden days. I know they're subject to a 'single definition' rule but wasn't aware they were implicitly inline.

Comment: I've edited in some further explanation of why `int` is preferable to `unsigned` in this context. If you're still unconvinced, well, let's agree to disagree. Re "lock" versus "mutex": C++ doesn't have anything called a "spinlock"; instead it has `atomic_flag`, which sidesteps the whole issue. Both `mutex` and `unique_lock<mutex>` conform to the *Lockable* concept; but I maintain that the two notions of "a mutex" and "a lock taken *on that mutex*" are two very different things, and therefore it's useful to keep them as distinct notions in your mind.

Comment: The very strong argument against willy nilly signed types is that you don't get lots of really useful 'conversion/comparison between signed and unsigned type' warnings. They're almost always a problem and so very often a bug. If you just throw out unsigned from your vocabulary your inviting a whole bunch of nasties. Many of which mean loops run 'forever'. I very strongly recommend keeping the notions of signed and unsigned integral types separate. It will clean up endless logic. As I said, Java not doing it taught me that wisdom.

Comment: My rationale is that `mutex` is a kind of lock. Correct it conforms to lockable so that's great. A spin-lock (if you implement one) is another likd of lock. People will think a spin-mutex is somehow backed by an explicit platform mutex construct - which it may not. A lock_guard definitely isn't a lock and doesn't implement lockable. It guards a lock. unique_lock is a lock and is clearly named on the pattern of unique_ptr (and behaves in an analogous way). That all makes sense and it doesn't require us to think all locks are mutexes (even though they are).

Comment: Sorry, you're mistaken. Locks and mutexes are *different things* in C++. Mutexes reside in dedicated memory locations and behave sort of like physical padlocks. A *lock*, OTOH, is an abstract *value* type (not necessarily residing in a specific memory location; for example `unique_lock<T>` is moveable) that provides an RAII notion of "a-lock-on-a-mutex"; for this reason all *locks* in the STL are parametrized by the type of the mutex they control. For example, `lock_guard<T>`, `unique_lock<T>`, and `shared_lock<T>`. Keep working with concurrency in C++; you'll see the pattern eventually. :)

Comment: I think it's simpler to see mutex as a kind of lock. That's particularly since as you pointed out it implements lockable. Very confusing in an OO language where 'what you can do is what you are' for it to be lockable and not a lock.

Comment: Thanks for all this. Along with other help on a related question I put in Stackoverflow I'll post a revised class with many of your suggestions later. One interesting fact is that this hybrid using an `std::atomic_flag` to avoid `std::mutex` calls is faster on my platform. It's about 4 times faster to succeed (or fail) `try_lock()`. That's even taking into account the additional `notify_one()` work in unlock and resolving the race condition in the code (the race is between `wait()` and `clear_flag`/`notify_one()`).

Comment: What does the bug (great find, btw) have to do with suffixing data members with `_`? Wouldn't have changed anything about this code. Still would've unfortunately compiled just fine.

Comment: I've already forgotten why I said that. :) I think I was using "suffix with `_`" as a shorthand for "use a naming convention for members that won't collide with any other names in scope" — in which case Dan's `mFoo` convention would also be fine... so maybe I meant something different at the time, but if so I can't think of it now.

Comment: This answer is the winner of [Best of Code Review 2015 — Exterminator category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6427). Congratulations!

Comment: The blog post for "unsigned considered harmful" does not cover the performance issue:  signed values generate faster code due to optimization opportunity.  You can find presentations showing extreme examples of this in conference videos from a few years ago.